# Loading images for multi-class from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning

I have Train and Test folders and inside each folder there is many folders with images inside each. In .csv file there is label for each folder and class.

here is csv file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pRsu.png

and folders

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wfKb.png

How to load these folders with labels in keras ?

I tried to make a dataframe with folders and labels like below :

```
 pth = 'C:/Users/Documents/train/'  
 folders =  os.listdir(pth)
 filepath='C:/Users//Documents//keras/labels.csv'
 metadf = pd.read_csv(filepath)
 metadf.index = metadf.Class


 videos = pd.DataFrame([])
 for folder in folders:
   pth_upd = pth + folder + '/'
 for file in allfiles:
 videos = pd.DataFrame(metadf.values, index=folders)
```

the output is :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kykDv.png

Is that the correct way of doing it ? how can I load each folder with images and corresponding labels ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuild flow_from_directory() method
   check out this link [keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: I think  flow_from_directory()  works on images inside directory , not in my case nested folders